# How to marshal & unmarshal an x509.Certificate to/from JSON?

Tags: json, go, ssl-certificate, x509

I have a struct which looks like this, where PrivateKey & PublicKey are own types mapping to `[]byte`:

```
type Secret struct {
    Cert     *x509.Certificate
    ValidFor string
    Private  PrivateKey
    Public   PublicKey
}
```

This struct is embedded as a field in another structure, which gets marshalled into a JSON. Marshalling the outer structure seems to work fine and the JSON looks okay, however unmarshalling seems to cause the following error:

```
json: cannot unmarshal number json: cannot unmarshal number 54368953042[...number shortened...] into Go struct field Certificate.Secrets.Cert.PublicKey of type float64
```

Obviously, it seems that the unmarshaller is tripping on the big.int which contains the public key. Now, I found a solution online [which tells me to first unmarshal to a `map[string]interface{}`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/Fo5fTnUNIwo), however given that my structs are a bit more nested, this seems like an exhaustive solution.

Now I'm wondering, is there any easier way to marshal & unmarshal a x509.Certificate with big.Ints in it? Or is the best way indeed to manually store, replace & restore problematic fields?

Comment: you can use pem which is mainly base64: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail

Comment: Make your `*Key` types implement [`encoding/json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) and serialize these numbers in any way you're comfortable with.